# Oracle reports builder number wraping

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

I was wondering how to make your numbers wrap in report fields, i tried to set vertical elasticity to expand and to variable, but if i run out of width it's just showing stars instead of numbers. Tried looking everywhere didn't find any other solutions besides the elasticity ones. I am using 11.1.12.0 version of the reports builder tool. Appreciate your help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer in oracle community forum, it seems you have to convert numbers to characters if you want the wrap effect, hese is the answer. "You may have to create a place to hold the summary value converted to char, or use a format trigger, but, as it's a very big number, if you are going to use a mask, I think you'll need to enter a very long mask, like '999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G999G990D00'
because I don't think oracle has something like excel's masks:  #,##0.00"